# Cannot query for disabled select elements

Tags: javascript, select, input, queryselector

I can select all inputs that aren't disabled but for some reason the method doesn't work on select elements.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled])');
```

Is there another way to query non-disabled Selects ? I can't say if the :not selector isn't working or if there is some rule that prevents the selector from working.

Ty for our answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query for non-disabled selects just as you have in your selector. Including an actual example (HTML) of your issue may show that you have another issue.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([disabled]),select:not([disabled])')
  .forEach(input => console.log(input.value));
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="found-input" />
<input type="text" value="not-found-input" disabled />
<select><option value="found-select" selected></option></select>
<select disabled><option value="not-found-select" selected></option></select>
```